# how to stop if statement from executing a command bash?

Tags: bash

I am trying to check if a particular string contains a substring. **It happens that the substring is also a command, which I do not want to execute but every time the if statement is hit, it does try to execute**. How to stop it?

This is the part I am talking about:

```
if [[ "$installed" == *"$package"* ]]
then
     "$package" >> $filename
fi
```

And this is the rest of the script:

```
 read -p "enter first ID from yum History to search " startId
 read -p "enter the last ID from yum history to search " endId

 #getting undone operations so we can skip on them
 undone=$(sudo yum history info $startId..$endId | grep Command | grep undo | awk {print$6}'|column)

 echo "those operations were undone so we won\'t take them under consideration "$undone

 #getting a list of installed packages
 installed=$(sudo yum list installed | column)

 read -r -p "enter an absolute path and a file name to save your result  " filename

  $(sudo touch "$filename")

  #setting up a counter for a while loop
  counter=1

  while [ $counter -le $endId ]
  do
  if [[ "$undone" != *"$counter"* ]]
    then

            printer=1
            package="something"
            while [[ ! -z $package ]]
            do
            #get info about a particular history record, get the command, split by ":", 
            #print what's on the other side of ":", remove "re" and "install", and -y, 
            #separate by spaces and print 1st word and then second.
            package=`sudo yum history info $counter | grep Command | awk -F":" '{print$2}'| grep install | sed s/'re'// | sed s/'install'// | sed s/'-y'//| awk -F' ' '{print$'$printer'}'`
            ((printer++))
           
HERE>>>>>          if [[ "$installed" == *"$package"* ]]
                    then
                            "$package" >> $filename
                    fi
            done
            ((counter++))
    else
            echo "this operation was undone".$counter
            ((counter++))
    fi   
done
$(sudo sort -u $filename -o $filename)
```

Output when running with -x option:

```
+ [[ Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-
              : manager
Installed Packages
.
.
.
zlib-devel.x86_64                    1.2.7-18.el7            @rhel-server-local  == *mcelog.x86_64* ]]
+ mcelog.x86_64
history: line 43: mcelog.x86_64: command not found
+ [[ ! -z mcelog.x86_64 ]]
```

Comment: `[[ ... ]]` won't execute a command; the arguments are treated as data only.

Comment: I added a run with -x option to improve details on the question.

Comment: The problem is `"$package" >> $filename`; that should probably be `echo "$package" >> "$filename"`

Comment: `$(sudo touch "$filename")` would also be a problem, if `touch` actually produced any output. You only need `sudo touch "$filename"`, although I question whether you need `sudo`. (If you do, you later attempts to write to `"$filename"` will probably fail due to lack of permissions.)

Comment: @chepner that was it! Works perfectly now!

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create an answer instead.